# Restore SQL Server 2008 backup to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, backup, restore

Can you restore SQL Server 2008 backup to SQL Server 2016 ?
Thank you

Comment: If you're asking, is there any reason you couldn't have tried it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. SQL Server is backward compatible with any version that was **supported** at the time the version was released.

For SQL Server 2016 that was SQL Server 2008-2014.

A full list of the compatibility modes available can be found on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#arguments).

Note that **restoring a database on a newer version of SQL Server is a one way process**. The database, from an older version, will be upgraded to work on the newer version and set to the appropriate compatibility level. You cannot restore a compatibility 100 database from SQL Server 2016 on a SQL Server 2008 instance (or anything else prior to 2016).